# Gallian's Exercise 4.76: a 2008 GRE practice exam question: "exactly two of $x^3$, $x^5$, and $x^9$ are equal, determine $\lvert x^{13}\rvert$".

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

This question appears to be new here according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Gallian+2008+GRE+practice+exam) and [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Cyclic%20group%20of%20order%2015%2C%20%24Exactly%5C%20two%5C%20of%5C%20x%5E3%2C%5C%20x%5E5%2C%5C%20and%5C%20x%5E9%5C%20are%5C%20equal%24%2C%20%24%5Cleft%7Cx%5E%7B%5Cleft%5C%7B13%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%5Cright%7C%24&p=1).

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 4.76 *ibid.* and it's stated to be a problem from a 2008 GRE practice exam.

**I would like to prove this result using the tools given in the textbook prior to this exercise.** (A free copy of the book is available online.)

### The Question:

> If $x$ is an element of a cyclic group of order $15$ and exactly two of $x^3$, $x^5$, and $x^9$ are equal, determine $\lvert x^{13}\rvert$.

### My Attempt:

My first concern is whether it's the order of the *group*, let's call it $G$, or of the *element*, called $x$, that is $15$. Nonetheless, here are some thoughts, since $x^{15}=e$ either way:

- If $x^3=x^5$, then $x^2=e$, but then either $x=e$ or $\lvert x\rvert=2$; in the former case, $\lvert x^{13}\rvert=\lvert e\rvert=0$, but in the latter, $$\begin{align}0&=\lvert x^{15}\rvert\\ &=\lvert (x^2)^7x\rvert \\ &=\lvert x\rvert\\ &=2;\end{align}$$ thus $\lvert x^{13}\rvert=0$. (*EDIT*: But [$x\neq e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080960/gallians-exercise-4-76-a-2008-gre-practice-exam-question-exactly-two-of-x3#comment6351897_3080960).)
- If $x^3=x^9$, then $x^6=e$, so $e=x^{15}=(x^6)^2x^3=x^3$, which means $x=e$ or $\lvert x\rvert=3$; thus $\lvert x^{13}\rvert=0$ as before or $$\boxed{\begin{align}\lvert x^{13}\rvert &=\lvert (x^3)^4x\rvert \\ &=\lvert x\rvert\\ &=3.\end{align}}$$ (*EDIT*: But [$x\neq e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080960/gallians-exercise-4-76-a-2008-gre-practice-exam-question-exactly-two-of-x3#comment6351897_3080960).)
- If $x^5=x^9$, then $x^4=e$, but now $e=x^{15}=(x^4)^3x^3=x^3$, so that $x^3=x^4$ implies $x=e$; hence $\lvert x^{13}\rvert=0$. (*EDIT*: But [$x\neq e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080960/gallians-exercise-4-76-a-2008-gre-practice-exam-question-exactly-two-of-x3#comment6351897_3080960).)

[*EDIT 2:* The boxed bit is the only answer.]

> Is this correct? What would be a better way of determining $\lvert x^{13}\rvert$?

Please help :)

Comment: We should interpret that the order of the group is $15$.  The properties asserted for $x$ rule out that it could have order $15$.  Of course $x$ will generate a *subgroup* of the same order as $x$.

Comment: I've just noticed that the *"exactly two"* specification of the powers eliminates the $x=e$ cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^3,\,x^5,\,x^9$ aren't all equal, $|x|$ is positive and not $2$. Instead, it divides $4$ or $6$ (and thus $12$) and also $15$ but not $2$, so $x^{13}=x\implies|x^{13}|=|x|=3$.

Comment: This seems very slick. Thank you. How did you get $\lvert x\rvert=3$ though?

Comment: @Shaun $|x|\le 2$ contradicts the setup, and $3$ if the only other common factor of $12$ and $15$.

Comment: Thank you. That's very clear now :)